# Turning 2D Trajectories Into 2D Geodesics

Tags: geometry, geodesic

First and foremost let me warn you, potential enlightener to my ignorance, that I'm waaaay out of my element here, so forgive any lack of information or rigor in my statements.

So I have a trajectory of a point in a closed bidimensional plane, that is the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the 2D-point are bound , like angles.

What I want to do is, I want to twist and deform this plane such that the arbitrary trajectory described by the point is a *geodesic* in the new twisted crazy plane. Is there a way to figure that out? How do I even put that in mathematical statements?

Then again, forgive me for being so ultra-vague.

Comment: You minimize the arc length of the loop to get a geodesic.

Comment: Oh... Oh, I guess I made myself misunderstood. Sorry Sanath. What I mean is that the plane is closed. The trajectory is arbitrary in that plane, it is not neccessarily a loop. It is just that the coordinates are bound variables so the point can leave on one side of the plane and it'll show up on the opposite side.

Comment: Oh - I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it, your $x$ and $y$ values are not only bounded, but identified at the boundary, so e.g. in the angle example, $x=180°$ is essentially the same as $x=-180°$. You should make the topology of the “plane” reflect that identification. If you start with a rectangular sheet of rubber, and glue its top edge to its bottom edge, and then the resulting left boundary circle to the right boundary circle, you obtain a torus. At least if you keep edges aligned the same way, otherwise things become more difficult. So topologically you'd describe your setup not as a plane but as a torus, in order to get this wrap-around behavior.

If wrap-around is your only concern, then you could simply choose a simple “flat” metric for the torus and the trajectories should become geodesics. If there are other things affecting your trajectories so that they are no straight lines even when they don't cross the boundary, then you'll have to tell us more about how these trajectories will be shaped. After all, you can't expect a space where *every* trajectory someone might think of will become a geodesic.

By the way, this concept of “choosing a metric” is just the formal equivalent of your “twist and deform” idea. It is often easier to assume that your space stays fixed and your rulers and other measurement instruments bend and twist depending on location, and the results are largely equiavelent. Unless you need to embed your manifold (i.e. plane, torus, …) into a flat three-dimensional space in such a way that measurements stay true. There are cases where you can choose a metric to satisfy your needs but still find no “isometric embedding” into $\mathbb R^3$. For example, you cannot find an isometric embedding of a topological torus with a flat metric unless you not only bend but actually fold the manifold. The result looks like folded paper, the different sheets incident with the same points in space.

Comment: Okay... Now it seems like we're going where I intended. Yes, apparently my plane is actually a torus because it has all those properties you mentioned. An no, the "wrap-around" isn't the only important thing, it is just a thing. The trajectory is relatively arbitrary in the torus. What I want is this: How can I systematically try out "metrics" until I find one in which that trajectory, in particular, is a geodesic. How can I test it? What sort of quantity I should "optimize" in that search? How do I know I'm getting close in my search?

Comment: @urquiza: For “relatively arbitrary” trajectories, the metric can be “relatively arbitrary” as well, both in value and in structure. And if you don't know the structure of the metric, you don't know what parameters you can tune, and how to tune them. So you really have to make an effort to get rid of this “relatively arbitrary”, and put an effort into describing the kinds of trajectories you may encounter.

Comment: I don't think I follow just what "value and structure" means in the context. Could you please give some practical examples?

Comment: For example, you could start with a common Cartesian coordinate system of the plane, and then consider metrics which are polynomials of a certain degree. The “structure” would be “polynomial” and the “value” would be determined by the actual coefficients of that polynomial. If you can tell that there will be a polynomial metric to satisfy your requirements, looking for coefficients starts to make sense. But for “relatively arbitrary”, you don't know that polynomials will be sufficient.

Comment: Aaah yes, yes. I had that in mind, yes. You mean that the warping of the thing is done in a systematic way. Yes, yes, it will be. Let's assume then that the metric is a linear combination of these polynomials of order $n$. How would I come about to finding parameters for this metric such that this trajectory in the torus is a geodesic? I should have probably put a "computational" tag in my post by now...

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say here is this: Once I know the metric is there a general optimization procedure to find the "coefficients"? A quantity to optimize or something. The "geodesicness" of the curve or something... Because if I have a grasp of the general procedure I could try out a lot of different structures, you know? Turns out that these trajectories represent physical data so finding out a metric in which they are geodesics would be cool, hence my interest in the general procedure. I don't know beforehand about the metrics, I need a way to try things out.

Comment: @urquiza: Sorry, don't know enough here yet to provide a simple measure for “geodesicness”. I don't even know whether polynomial metrics make sense. I guess I'd probably discretize stuff, so you can use graph search algorithms like Dijkstra to find approximate geodesics. But that would be more like an experiment, not sure whether that approach is feasible.