# Formalize idea of 'homeomorphism that preserves geodesics'?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geodesic, metric-geometry

**I am seeking to formalize the following idea**: Take a sheet of paper and lay it flat on a table. Choose two points A and B on the paper, then draw a line segment from A to B. Fold the sheet of paper so that the crease lays across the line segment, then reopen it so that no part of the paper touches itself. Then [*it seems to me that*] that the shortest path from A to B while staying on the sheet of paper is marked out by the image of the line segment.

**What I have tried**: Formally we could identify manifold $M$ as the original sheet of paper, manifold $N$ as the result of folding and then reopening the paper, and $f : M \rightarrow N$ as the actions of 'fold and then reopen'. I think that $f$ can be taken as a homeomorphism, but I hesitate to call $f$ a [geodesic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_map) as $N$ is not smooth. How can I describe what $f$ is?

(I consulted the answers to earlier questions about [turning 2D trajectories into 2D geodesics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705777/turning-2d-trajectories-into-2d-geodesics/706472#706472) and [length-minimizing curves being geodesics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865078/length-minimizing-curves-are-geodesic-segments), and also Petrunin & Yashinski's very-approachable lectures on piecewise distance preserving maps. The formalisms there didn't quite seem to fit.)

*Petrunin, Anton; Yashinski, Allan*, [**Lectures on piecewise distance preserving maps**](http://www.oalib.com/paper/3977447), Mathematics (2014)

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off with some notion from metric geometry? If you put the intrinsic path metric on $N,$ then the fact you're interested in is that $f$ is an *affine map* between *geodesic length spaces*.

Comment: @[Anthony Carapetis] many thanks for the comment, I have been reading up on _length spaces_ as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ and $N$ be length spaces. The requirement is that $f$ is a homeomorphism that *preserves shortest paths*.

**Details**

Let $x, y$ be any two points in $M$. Since $M$ is a [length spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric), there exists a path $\phi$ of finite length from $x$ to $y$ and the length of that path is equal to the distance from $x$ to $y$. We may refer to $\phi$ as being *a shortest path* from $x$ to $y$ (there may be many shortest paths, but at least one such path exists).

Now suppose that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $M$ to $N$. Then $f \circ \phi$ is a path in $N$ as homeomorphisms preserve continuity. The question to ask is, "Is $f \circ \phi$ necessarily a **shortest** path from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$?"

I think the answer is "no" by counter-example: 
Let $M = S^2 - \{(0,0,1), (0,0,-1)\}$, $N = [-\pi,\pi) \times (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and $f : M \rightarrow N$ be the [plate carrée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) projection ($f$ maps from the surface of the Earth to a flat sheet of paper but omits the North and South Poles). Then $f$ is a homeomorphism but it does not preserve shortest paths - the great circles on $M$ are *not* necessarily mapped to line segments in $N$ (unlike the [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)). Indeed $f$ is also an example of a diffeomorphism that is *not* a geodesic map (when considering $M$ and $N$ as manifolds).

*(This is a provisional answer based on comments by @[Anthony Carapetis]. I am very open to accepting a better one.)*